# Creating a separate network without physical adapters on ESXi

Tags: networking, virtual-machines, vmware-vsphere

I have an VM running on ESXi that I need to isolate from the network but still have access to the outside world. I have looked into creating a new virtual switch but we dont have any spare physical adapters available. Am I on the right track or is there another way of doing this?

Edit:

Apologies for not being clearer. Basically we have a VMWare Sphere hosting multiple VMs. On one of the VMs, we are testing a piece of software and it requires to be isolated from the current network ( internal ) but still have external access ( internet ). One of the ways to do this I believe is to create a virtual switch on its own subnet and bridge it somehow.

I have an album containing the following:

- vSwitch0
- vSwitch1
- vSwitch2
- Physical Adpaters
- Issue with creating new virtual switch

https://i.stack.imgur.com/vHKBs.jpg

Comment: You need to clarify - you say 'host' - do you mean 'VM'? You need to be clearer - have you an image of your VSS/VDS?

Comment: `I have an ESXi host within that I need to isolate from the network but still have access to the outside world.` - That statement contradicts itself. Can you clarify what you're trying to do?

Comment: Hi there, I have made an edit to my question. Apologies for not being clearer. By VSS/VDS i guess that means my virtual switch mappings?

Comment: Right, thanks for the update, a few things - VMware is a company, vSphere is a combination of their products, ESXi is the hypervisor you're using, a Host is the (usually) physical server you're running ESXi on and a VM is a VM, a VSS is a standard virtual switch, a VDS is a distributed virtual switch. In order to answer your question we will need to see how your virtual switch/es are configured - we'll need to know what physical NICs are in the servers, what they connect to outside the server and how the virtual switch is configured.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up for me. I forgot to add the reason we need the external access is because an external company requires access to test their software but want it isolated from our current network. I will include some screen shots in the above of the VSS and VDS configuration.

Comment: Thanks for the update - am I right in thinking that you have no current external internet connection in the environment shown in the pictures?

Comment: The VMs do have external access to the internet as I am able to browse the web on them.

Comment: via which vswitch, port group and physical link/s?

Answer (score 1):

You could create two virtual switches, put the test machine on one switch, and then create a router VM, for example pfSense, that has two NICs, one on each vSwitch. Then you can configure the firewall/router however you see fit.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new VLAN for test on your Core switch,configure the server farm switch where the ESX network adapters are connected to trunk mode and allow both VLANs (test & production) .Create new portgroup in Vsphere networking with VLAN ID tags.Assign the VLAN tag of test VLAN to test server which will be isolated from the production VMs.